# vlan on top of vlan-aware bridge: possible and how?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, vlan, bridge

I'm currently working on configuring an opensuse host as a KVM hypervisor.

I have a physical interface as slave for a bridge.
I'm going to make this bridge interface vlan-aware and handle the VLAN-configuration inside of the VM's itself.

However, I also want to make sure that the bridge interface itself is member of a separate vlan and gets an IP address in that VLAN (statically assigned). This will be necessary to be able to SSH into the hypervisor from that separate vlan to manage the hypervisor and the VM's.

There is only one physical network interface in the host.
Is this even possible, using nmcli? And how would that be possible then?

I was thinking to define a vlan interface on top of the bridge and make sure the vlan interface gets an IP but the underlying bridge doesn't (but is vlan aware).
So basically: enp0s1 -> br0 (vlan aware, no ip) -> br0.vlan (static ip).

OR:

I define a separate vlan interface on the physical interface, so:
enp0s1 -> br0 (vlan aware, no ip) + enp0s1.vlan with static ip.

What would be the approach to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried separate VLAN Interface on the Physical Interface Alternatively? you can create a separate VLAN interface directly on the physical interface and assign the static IP address to it. All via `nmcli`

Comment: So basically that's the second option in my question then? So does that work, that a physical interface on the one hand is a slave to a bridge and on the other hand also has a vlan interface associated with it?

Comment: Basically, you want to trunk. VLAN tags are applied on the the frames of a trunk in order that the endpoints, e.g. switches, can separate the frames to the proper VLANs. One VLAN on a trunk can be untagged and still know that it is separate from the others, and that is called the "native" VLAN for that trunk link. By default, VLAN 1 is both the default VLAN and the native VLAN. All VLAN-aware switches do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

So my understanding of "VLAN Interface on top of the Bridge" by using `nmcli`:

(I have tested it on Slackware VM but I think it works on production server)

**First option:** VLAN Interface on top of the Bridge

```
# First create a bridge interface.
nmcli connection add type bridge con-name br0 ifname br0 stp yes

# Then modifying the bridge VLAN-aware.
nmcli connection modify br0 bridge.vlan_filtering yes

# Now add the VLAN interface on top of the bridge.
nmcli connection add type vlan con-name br0.vlan dev br0 id {YOUR_VLAN_ID}

# Finally modify the connection to assign a static IP address to the VLAN interface
nmcli connection modify br0.vlan ipv4.address {IPADDRESS}/{SUBNETMASK}
```

**Second option**: Separate VLAN Interface on the physical interface:

```
# First we create the VLAN interface on the physical interface.
nmcli connection add type vlan con-name enp0s1.vlan dev enp0s1 id {YOUR_VLAN_ID}

# Then modify the connection to assign a static IP address to the VLAN interface.
nmcli connection modify enp0s1.vlan ipv4.address {IPADDRESS}/{SUBNET_MASK}
```

I think there is not best approach, it's all about your **network setup**.

Comment: Yep, I tried this yesterday also in a VM and this indeed seems to work. However I'm wondering if the second option is also correct/feasible and which one is the best approach?

Comment: @aquilares I have added the second option, take a look.